# i cant access index of map function within function call on button(onClick()), which is within scope of map(),code is below

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, next.js

**Initial State**

```
const [variation, setVariation] = useState([
    {
      name: "",
      value: [""],
    },
  ]);
```

**function on button click**

```
const addValueField = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const field = [...variation];
    field[index].value.push("");
    setVariation(field);
  };
```

**html render:**

```
<div>
 {variation.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              key={index}
              className="bg-base-200 m-1 shadow appearance-none border rounded text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Variation Type"
            />
            <div className="form-control">
              {variation[index].value.map((value, i) => {
                return (
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    key={i}
                    className="bg-base-200 m-1 shadow appearance-none border rounded text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                    placeholder="Enter Value"
                  />
                );
              })}
              <button onClick={(e, index) => addValueField(e, index)}>
                Add another value
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
</div>
```

When addValueField(e,index) is called on button click, it does not pick the index of parent map(), but button is within parent map() scope, so it does not pass index to the function and error is generated.

Comment: It should be `<button onClick={(e) => addValueField(e, index)}>` . You have used `index` of `onClick`, but there is no arguments passed to `onClick` callback function

Comment: Exactly, if you use `(e, index)` as parameter list, `index` will shadow the actual `index` from the `.map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick` doesn't give you the `index`. You have to get the index from the `map` directly if you use as

```
<button onClick={(e) => addValueField(e, index)}>
  Add another value
</button>;
```

and you can set `variation` state as

```
const addValueField = (e, index) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setVariation((state) =>
    state.map((o, i) => (i === index ? { ...o, value: [...o.value, ""] } : o))
  );
};
```